# How can I output id number in excel without error warning

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using POI to output a product id into excel cell. The product id is a numeric string like
"0000001", "3212230".

After the excel is generated, I found the cell holds this id value has an error check warning  "**The number in this cell is formated as text or preceded by an apostrophe**". If I double click on this cell in excel, it will automatically correct "0000001" to 1, which is not what I want. I know I can turn the error checking option off in excel manually, but that's not what I want.

Is there anyway to keep excel quiet and considering this id as a text?
Here is the code snippet:

```
   cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
   cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString( quote.getQuoteId() )); 
   cell.setCellStyle(styles.get("table_t"));
```

Comment: Can you not set the value as a number, then apply a formatting rule to make it have the required number of digits?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not supported yet by POI. However, the low level implementation seems to be done as part of [bug 46136](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46136). This bug is waiting for suggestions for specifying an interface for this feature so I'd say the best to get this done one day would be to contribute your remarks and maybe vote for it. I just voted right now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you precede it with a single quote?

```
cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("'" & quote.getQuoteId() ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Excel really loves its numbers which is why that is considered an error. About the only thing that would make Excel happy would be to change your QuoteId format to start with a letter instead of being completely numeric.